# How to normalize data for all parameters at same range of scale

Tags: normalization, normalize

I have csv file,
Data :

yield  :    1172.4  , 1712.7 ,  863.88 , 2731.34  , 5220

Rain(mm):   113.6   ,  152.3  , 181.9 ,  152.3   ,  125.3

dummy(types_of_soil)   :     1     ,   0     ,  0  ,    2    ,  1

dummy variable : 
1 ==> Medium black soil

0 ==>  deep black

2 ==> Radish brown

Dependent variable ( y) :  yield

Independent variable : Rain , dummy(types of soil)

So, I want to normalize this data, How to scale data in range of 1 to 10 ?

I have try to use formula :
(xi - min ) / (max - min )
Is it correct ?

and how to scale data for binary variable(dummy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to normalize data

```
import pandas
import scipy
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
url = "filename.csv"
names = ['yield','Rain','types of soil']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
# separate array into input and output components
X = array[:,]  **select x independent variable**
Y = array[:,]  **select y dependent variable**
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
# summarize transformed data
numpy.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(rescaledX[0:5,:])
```

for more details . see this link 
http://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-data-machine-learning-python-scikit-learn/